# _init__() takes exactly 4 arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:28:27) [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2

I'm trying to instantiate instances of a User class in user.py based on the number of command-line arguments passed to a python program. I'm getting `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)` Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, argparse
from user import User

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Parse args
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Batch insert")
  parser.add_argument('-d','--dbfilepath', dest='dbfilepath', help='Absolute path and filename of the sqlite database file', required=False, default='/usr/local/foo/bar.sqlite')
  parser.add_argument('-v','--verbose', dest='verbose', help='Verbose output', required=False, action='store_true')
  parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='comma-delimited list of username password pairs', required=True, type=str)
  args = parser.parse_args()
  my_list = [str(item) for item in args.list.split(',')]
  # Only continue if we have even number of items in the un/pw list
  if len(my_list) % 2 == 0:
    count = 0
    u = User(args.dbfilepath, args.verbose)
    while (count < len(my_list)):
      u.create(my_list[count], my_list[count+1])
      count = count + 1
```

file user.py:

```
class User:

  def __init__(self, dbfilepath, verbose=False):
    self._verbose = verbose

    # Open DB and get cursor
    self._con = sqlite3.connect(dbfilepath)
    self._cursor = self._con.cursor()
```

execution:

```
./batch-insert.py -d /tmp/sql.sqlite -v --list stinky,cat

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create-users-batch.py", line 15, in <module>
    u = User(args.dbfilepath, args.verbose)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

What am I doing wrong? Both files are in the same directory.

Comment: Is there user.pyc file in the same directory that was from an earlier time when User took an extra arg?

Comment: @BryanOakley, no but to make sure, I deleted user.pyc and tried again. Same problem.

Comment: Yeah, you are grabbing a different `User` than you think you are. `import user;print user.__file__` would be interesting.

Comment: @tdelaney: `Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:28:27) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import user;print user.__file__
**user.pyc**

Comment: okay, shot in the dark... is `class User` defined twice in `user.py`?! Python has found a class called User whose init takes 3 args (plus self). There aren't a lot of options where it could be (just the user module, really).

Comment: Are there two `__init__` 's defined in `User`?

Comment: @tdelaney: no and no. But I moved the code to another machine and the problem is gone. Some environment issue...